# Is F# supported in Visual Studio Express 2013 RC?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to add support for F# to any of the Visual Studio Express 2013 RC versions (Web, Windows desktop, etc)?

Comment: I've already done some F# coding in the 2013 RC. If it's not there, make sure you've installed everything. Also keep in mind that if you're looking for project templates, pretty much anything for F# is online.

Answer (score 3):

Visual F# is now available for Visual Studio 2013 [Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop) and [Web](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-web) Express editions:

- [Announcing Visual F# Tools 3.1.1, with support for Desktop and Web express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/01/22/announcing-visual-f-3-1-1-and-support-for-desktop-express.aspx)

The installer [package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41654) can also be used in build server and virtual machine scenarios without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for F# on any of the pre-release Express SKUs for VS 2013.  It's there in the Ultimate SKU, though, and the pre-release versions are free...

For VS 2012 RTM, the Web Express SKU supported F# via an add-in.  You can draw your own conclusions about what will happen at VS 2013 RTM...

Answer (score 0):

F# is included in the Visual Studio 2013 editions at least according to this blog post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx